# How can I read a Cascading one line key value dataset

Tags: c++, json, string, list

I have the following problem:
I need to create a reader for a cascading one line key vaule dataset that looks something like this:
(for readability and put in newlines and tabs, but in the actual code its diffrent data and on one line)

```
'name:thomas,country:usa,birthday:1934,height:140,face:'
     eyes:'
          color:blue,sight:good    
     '
     hair:'
          lenght:long,color:brown,
     '
   '
   hands:'
      size:small,fingernails:clean
   '     
'
'name:laura:country:germany,etc...'
```

So I basicly need this thing to understand that if a new ' comes after a key, it should be read as a value, not as a new set of key value pairs.
Ideally it should just give a string that can then turned into another list, which understands the same thing again.
The Problem I have right now is, how do I make the programm understand which ' end the current casced list and which beginn a new one. 
I have used std::split so far, but I doesn'tm seam to be possible to solve this problem this way.
Is there some header only way I could just use?
And I also can't change the file format to xml or json, since the one line cascaded list thing is not on my end.

Comment: You can do wonderful things with loops/`std::getline`/`std::istringstream`. What have you tried?

Comment: Yeah but there are no lines, its all one liners. I just made it look nice for overviews sake

Comment: `std::getline` accepts a custom delimiting character.

Comment: thanks, ill have a look

Comment: That doesn't seam to fix my problem in any way, since the function cannot differentiate between starting ' and ending '